# Set an activity on the activity stack

Tags: android

I'd like to set my newly created activity to be the only one on the stack and be on top of it as well, so when Activity B is created from A, I can press back to return to home menu from B.

Accordingly, this is what I did

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,B.class);

    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

For some reason, after Activity B starts, pressing back still takes me to A.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(this,B.class);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish(); // to end the current activity
}
```

call **finish()** after startactivity(...), so that `A activity ll removed from the stack`. when you press back button **A** activity ll be not there in stack.

Comment: my pleasure,I helped you out :) :)

Answer (score 1):

After you've called startActivity(i) in Activity A, you have to call finish(); - to finish the Activity. Then pressing back doesn't take you to A!

Answer (score 1):

change the activity in your manifest:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
              android:noHistory="true"
 >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, and I use it for the same:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, b.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```